# How do I replace the value of a dictionary that have multiple variables?

Tags: python, robotframework

"bootMode": {"manageMode": True, "mode": "UEFIOptimized"}

I would like to change the value of "mode": "UEFIOptimized to "mode": "UEFI".

Comment: You didn't indicate which language you're using.

Comment: I am using robot framework with keywords

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming your code is:

```
some_dict = { ..., "bootMode": {"manageMode": True, "mode": "UEFIOptimized"}, ... }
```

and the problem is that you have to change nested dict values. It's easier than you think.

```
sub_d = some_dict["bootMode"]  # the dictionary you want to change
sub_d["mode"]                  # the value you want to change
sub_d["mode"] = "UEFI"         # ...and how to change it.
```

All together, you have

```
some_dict["bootMode"]["mode"] = "UEFI"
```

Answer (score 1):

Collections has a [Set To Dictionary](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Collections.html#Set%20To%20Dictionary) keyword that is helpful here.

`Set To Dictionary    ${bootMode}    mode    UEFI`